# V2 documentation errors?

Tags: box-api

I am working on an application that will be using the V2 Box API and have noticed that for some calls the response I get from the API differs from the documentation.

How do you want me to handle what I find?
Do you want me to post these points as individual topics here?
Or is there another way to provide the feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You can send any documentation errors you find to API[at]BOXdotCOM.